# This export to excel is not working it only adds the columns

Tags: c#, sql, excel

So before it was working when it has the worbook.saveAs(); but i needed it to open an existing file then save it. not over write it.

i have tried using the methods shown in different questions here but all of them is replacing the current file and creating a new one.

```
            SqlConnection cnn;
            string connectionString = null;
            string sql = null;
            string data = null;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            string filename = @"D:\ExcelFiles\DatabaseComp.xls";

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Diether\Desktop\OJT KIOSK\DB_Kiosk.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cnn.Open();
            sql = "SELECT * FROM TBL_Company";
            SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dscmd.Fill(ds);

            foreach (dynamic worksheet in xlWorkBook.Worksheets)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells.ClearContents();
            }

            foreach (System.Data.DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < dt.Columns.Count; i1++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i1 + 1] = dt.Columns[i1].ColumnName;
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                int s = i + 1;
                for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[s + 1, j + 1] = data;
                }
            }
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            xlWorkBook.Save();
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: `open an existing file then save it. not over write it.` That's self-contradictory. Opening a file and saving it means overwriting the previous one. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: The sheet names in the workbook must be unique.  The database will always contain the same table names which is causing the old sheet to get over written.  So you could add a date time stamp to the sheet names or put a version number 1,2,3 on sheet names when sheet name already exists.

Comment: well is there a possible way that it only replaces the data in the first sheet ?